# React component being called twice due to React.StrictMode causing issues

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that is being called twice on render. I am assuming from my reading this is due to `React.StrictMode` but I am actually not sure. The component is called with the tag

```js
<UserPlaylist sortMode="new" tracks={this.state.items}/>
```

where `this.state.items` is a large object containing data that is to be mapped in the `UserPlaylist` component.

UserPlaylist Component:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import Track from '../components/track'

export default class UserPlaylist extends Component {

    async componentDidMount() {
        const sortMode = this.props.sortMode
        const tracks = this.props.tracks

        this.setState({
            sortMode,
            tracks
        });
    }

    render() {
        const mode = this.props.sortMode
        if(mode === "new"){
            console.log("sortMode:","new");
            return(
                <>
                {this.state.items.map(track => <Track key={track.id} trackObj={track}/>) }
                </>
            )
        }
        else{
            console.log("sortMode:",mode);
            return(
                <>
                {this.state.items.map(track => <Track key={track.id} trackObj={track}/>) }
                </>
            )
        }
    }
}
```

The issue lies in the fact that react seems to be trying to render it once before `this.state.items` is defined. Causing the `UserPlaylist` component to attempt to map `undefined` items.

Why is this happening? What am I supposed to be doing? Is this the best way to write a component that is sortable in the first place?

P.S. they both return the same thing right now on purpose. In practice, the `new` mode will be returning the same array but reversed. I plan to add a few other "modes" as well.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the part where you set the `items` state. (Is it supposed to be using the `tracks` state?) But assuming that is being done somewhere, I think your code is mostly fine, and in general this is a fine way of doing a sorted list.

I would recommend adding a kind of "loading" view (or just rendering nothing using `null`) for the case where the `items` state hasn't been initialized. For example:

```
render() {
    if (!this.state.items) {
      return null;
    }
    
    const mode = this.props.sortMode
    if(mode === "new"){
        console.log("sortMode:","new");
        return(
            <>
            {this.state.items.map(track => <Track key={track.id} trackObj={track}/>) }
            </>
        )
    }
    else{
        console.log("sortMode:",mode);
        return(
            <>
            {this.state.items.map(track => <Track key={track.id} trackObj={track}/>) }
            </>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: To clarify, this code will NOT run. Because in the "else" block, it is run once with "mode" and "items" set to undefined. This causes an error that will not allow the website to continue in dev mode. It errors out with `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')`. It's also worth mentioning it runs correctly if I remove the "else" part because then it only renders when items is defined (so yeah, tracks works right.)

Comment: This code produces the error `"TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'items')"`

Comment: It sounds like the `state` object is undefined. Can you try initializing the state? i.e. `state = {}`

Comment: Good call, that fixed the error, however now the component simply doesn't render at all, in any case

Comment: Using the code I provided? If nothing renders at all, that's because `this.state.items` is never set. Are you sure that you are setting the `items` state somewhere in your code? Just a guess, but it seems like you might be intending to use `tracks` instead of `items`?

Comment: I'm positive it is set, because before editing this and removing the "else" clause, it renders all of the content passed to it, that means that it is receiving and doing with the content what I want it to do